# How to compute options of dropdown for column filter in Flask Admin?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

In Flask Admin, I got a column of String values (I can't change the DB definition). When filtering this column in the index view, the user should be able to select the value from a dropdown.

The possible options for the filter should be computed when the user selects the filter. So I need a way to set the options based on a custom model query. Querying is rather fast as the column is indexed.

The [SQLA custom filter example](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/sqla-custom-filter/app.py) only shows how to apply a custom filter, but not how to make the options of a filter dynamic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The options parameter can be a callable so do something like the following (using the example you've linked to):

```
def get_all_last_names():
    unique_last_names = User.query.with_entities(User.last_name.distinct().label("last_name")).order_by(User.last_name.asc()).all()
    return [(user.last_name, user.last_name) for user in unique_last_names]

class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):

    column_filters = [
        FilterEqual(column=User.last_name, name='Last Name', options=get_all_last_names),
    ]

    # This is probably NOT the correct way to refresh the filters cache
    @expose('/')
    def index_view(self):
        self._refresh_filters_cache()
        return super(UserAdmin, self).index_view()
```

See single file demo below. Add new users and they will appear in the 'Last Name' filter. As pointed out by @sortas this version doesn't work when using the app factory method.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_admin import Admin, expose

# required for creating custom filters
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.filters import BaseSQLAFilter, FilterEqual

app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'

# Create in-memory database
app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'sample_db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# Flask views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


# Create model
class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    # Required for admin interface. For python 3 please use __str__ instead.
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username


# Create custom filter class
class FilterLastNameBrown(BaseSQLAFilter):
    def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
        if value == '1':
            return query.filter(self.column == "Brown")
        else:
            return query.filter(self.column != "Brown")

    def operation(self):
        return 'is Brown'


def get_options():
    return [('1', 'Yes'), ('0', 'No')]


def get_all_last_names():
    unique_last_names = User.query.with_entities(User.last_name.distinct().label("last_name")).order_by(
        User.last_name.asc()).all()
    return [(user.last_name, user.last_name) for user in unique_last_names]


# Add custom filter and standard FilterEqual to ModelView
class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):

    column_filters = [
        FilterEqual(column=User.last_name, name='Last Name', options=get_all_last_names),
        FilterLastNameBrown(column=User.last_name, name='Last Name', options=(('1', 'Yes'), ('0', 'No')))
    ]

    # This is probably NOT the correct way to refresh the filters cache
    @expose('/')
    def index_view(self):
        self._refresh_filters_cache()
        return super(UserAdmin, self).index_view()


admin = Admin(app, template_mode="bootstrap3")
admin.add_view(UserAdmin(User, db.session))


def build_sample_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    user_obj1 = User(first_name="Paul", last_name="Brown", username="pbrown", email="paul@gmail.com")
    user_obj2 = User(first_name="Luke", last_name="Brown", username="lbrown", email="luke@gmail.com")
    user_obj3 = User(first_name="Serge", last_name="Koval", username="skoval", email="serge@gmail.com")

    db.session.add_all([user_obj1, user_obj2, user_obj3])
    db.session.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_sample_db()
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Single file example when using app factory.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_admin import Admin, expose

# required for creating custom filters
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.filters import BaseSQLAFilter, FilterEqual

db = SQLAlchemy()


class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    # Required for admin interface. For python 3 please use __str__ instead.
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username


# Create custom filter class
class FilterLastNameBrown(BaseSQLAFilter):
    def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
        if value == '1':
            return query.filter(self.column == "Brown")
        else:
            return query.filter(self.column != "Brown")

    def operation(self):
        return 'is Brown'


def get_options():
    return [('1', 'Yes'), ('0', 'No')]


def get_all_last_names():
    unique_last_names = User.query.with_entities(User.last_name.distinct().label("last_name")).order_by(
        User.last_name.asc()).all()
    return [(user.last_name, user.last_name) for user in unique_last_names]


# Add custom filter and dynamic FilterEqual to ModelView
class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):

    column_filters = [
        FilterLastNameBrown(column=User.last_name, name='Last Name', options=(('1', 'Yes'), ('0', 'No')))
    ]

    def get_filters(self):
        _dynamic_filters = getattr(self, 'dynamic_filters', None)
        if _dynamic_filters:
            return (super(UserAdmin, self).get_filters() or []) + _dynamic_filters
        else:
            return super(UserAdmin, self).get_filters()

    @expose('/')
    def index_view(self):
        self.dynamic_filters = []
        self.dynamic_filters.extend([
            FilterEqual(column=User.last_name, name='Last Name', options=get_all_last_names),
            # Add further dynamic filters here
        ])
        self._refresh_filters_cache()
        return super(UserAdmin, self).index_view()


def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'

    # Create in-memory database
    app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'sample_db.sqlite'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
    db.init_app(app)
    admin = Admin(app, template_mode="bootstrap3")
    admin.add_view(UserAdmin(User, db.session))

    # Flask views
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'

    @app.before_first_request
    def build_sample_db():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        user_obj1 = User(first_name="Paul", last_name="Brown", username="pbrown", email="paul@gmail.com")
        user_obj2 = User(first_name="Luke", last_name="Brown", username="lbrown", email="luke@gmail.com")
        user_obj3 = User(first_name="Serge", last_name="Koval", username="skoval", email="serge@gmail.com")

        db.session.add_all([user_obj1, user_obj2, user_obj3])
        db.session.commit()

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Mmmh, this function gets called when the app is started. Even a page reload doesn't trigger it to be loaded again :-(

Comment: @Sebi - You need to update the filters cache - I've updated my answer

Comment: @pjcunningham Filters don't refresh even if use with app.app_context(), only manual app reload. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @sortas - Added a single file demo.

Comment: @pjcunningham Thanks, tried the same thing, but it looks like it doesn't work with app factories (`create_app()` and so on). So now I'm trying to override             `_refresh_filters_cache` method to query options from db every page reload.

Comment: @pjcunningham Added my version for app factories. Comment if possible :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use flask `has_request_context` function
to check if request context exists in function which returns options tuple for the filter.
It can help in a situation when options get from DB but request context not exist at that moment.

```
def _get_options_for_filter()
    if not has_request_context():
        return ()
    return tuple([(o.id, o.title) for o in Options.query.all()])
```

Comment: Thanks so much! A dynamic filter in the admin had blocked my alembic migrations by somehow locking the database tables, due to the refresh of the filter cache at startup.
Testing for the request context solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

Version for Flask app factories (`create_app`, `current_app`, `app_context` and so on) :)

```
# Dynamic filter update method for Flask app factories
# Override version of base _refresh_filters_cache method
def update_dynamic_filters(self, dynamic_filters):

    # Get base filters
    self._filters = self.get_filters()

    # Add dynamic filters (to the beginning)
    for dft in dynamic_filters:
        self._filters.insert(0, dft)

    if self._filters:
        self._filter_groups = OrderedDict()
        self._filter_args = {}

        for i, flt in enumerate(self._filters):
            key = as_unicode(flt.name)
            if key not in self._filter_groups:
                self._filter_groups[key] = FilterGroup(flt.name)
            self._filter_groups[key].append(
                {
                    'index': i,
                    'arg': self.get_filter_arg(i, flt),
                    'operation': flt.operation(),
                    'options': flt.get_options(self) or None,
                    'type': flt.data_type,
                }
            )
            self._filter_args[self.get_filter_arg(i, flt)] = (i, flt)
    else:
        self._filter_groups = None
        self._filter_args = None

# Update view every page reload (thanks to the @pjcunningham)
@expose('/')
def index_view(self):
    dynamic_filters = []
    # Working with db in app_context
    with app.app_context():
        # Adding dynamic filters
        dynamic_filters.append(
            FilterInList(
                column=Record.record_condition,
                name='Condition',
                options=[
                    (x[0], x[0])
                    for x in db.session.query(Record.record_condition)
                    .distinct()
                    .all()
                ],
            )
        )
    # Add dynamic filters to view
    self.update_dynamic_filters(dynamic_filters)
    return super(RecordView, self).index_view()
```

Comment: I think it's better to simply override `get_filters` rather than repeat the base code. Also, isn't the app context already established when `index_view` is called? I've added an app factory example to my answer based on your code.